# jQuery & CSS: how to convert this drawer menu from left to right?

Tags: jquery, css

It's a simple jQuery drawer menu that uses a toggle feature but I've never worked with 3D translations so I'm unsure of how to adjust this menu to slide from the right side instead of the left.

http://jsfiddle.net/mhGsR/

```
#site-wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }
#site-canvas {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
    transform:translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-transition:300ms ease all;
    transition:300ms ease all;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    }
.show-nav #site-canvas {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(300px);
    transform:translateX(300px);
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(300px,0,0);
    transform:translate3d(300px,0,0);
    }
#site-menu {
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-300px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    background:#428bca;
    padding:15px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `text-align: right;` to `#site-wrapper` and reverse the `300px` values that you have set.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/mhGsR/1/